# Input value is not seen completely, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

So, almost everything works as it should, the problem is when I type something in input it does not update the redux state completely. Example: if I type ABC it will send that to server via axios.post() like AB... If I type BEER it will send BEE ... It does not see the last letter or if I choose auto complete text on my device, it does not see the entire word if it is the last thing in the input....

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

```
  class AddressScreen extends Component {
      state = {
        usersNickOrName: "",
        usersAddress: "",
        usersPhoneNumber: ""
      };

      componentWillUpdate() {
    this.props.deliveryInfo(
      this.state.usersNickOrName,
      this.state.usersAddress,
      this.state.usersPhoneNumber
    );
  }

      onPressHandler = () => {


        let uid = this.props.uid;

        axios.post(
          `.../users/${uid}/info.json`,
          {
            nameOrNick: this.props.name,
            address: this.props.address,
            phoneNum: this.props.phoneNum
          }
        );
        this.props.navigator.pop();
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>

            <AnimatedForm delay={100} distance={10}>
              <AnimatedInput
               onChangeText={text => {
                  this.setState({ usersNickOrName: text });
                }}
              />
              <AnimatedInput
                onChangeText={text => {
                  this.setState({ usersAddress: text });
                }}
              />
              <AnimatedInput
                onChangeText={text => {
                  this.setState({ usersPhoneNumber: text });
                }}
              />

              <Animated.View style={styles.buttonView}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.button}
                  onPress={this.onPressHandler}
                >
                  <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>Dodaj Info</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </Animated.View>
            </AnimatedForm>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }



    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
        name: state.usersNickOrName,
        address: state.usersAddress,
        phoneNum: state.usersPhoneNumber,
        uid: state.userUid
      };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        deliveryInfo: (usersName, usersAddress, phoneNum) =>
          dispatch(deliveryInfo(usersName, usersAddress, phoneNum))
      };
    };

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(AddressScreen);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using the old state in `componentWillUpdate`. Use the next state instead.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  this.props.deliveryInfo(
    nextState.usersNickOrName,
    nextState.usersAddress,
    nextState.usersPhoneNumber
  );
}
```

Comment: note that componentWillUpdate is deprecated https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate

Comment: Thank you. When used nextState all works perfectly fine... About that depreciation... What should I do exactly? How can I  achieve the same efect w/o componentWillUpdate?

Comment: @FatBoyGebajzla [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is not deprecated, so you could use that instead.

Comment: @Tholle I tried componentDidUpdate, but I have the same behavior as before you told me to use nextState in componentWillUpdate...

Comment: @FatBoyGebajzla If you decide to use `componentDidUpdate` instead, then your state will have updated, so you should use `this.state.usersNickOrName` etc. again.

Comment: Thank you once again! Changed it and it works just fine. Cheers mate!